# Kubuntu 20.04 Random freezing problem while using Firefox

Tags: kubuntu, freeze, system

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 and I am experiencing random freezing while using my computer. The system completely freezes and I am only able to reset it pushing the power button.

I had this weird issue with an Nvidia card and, now that I have switched to an AMD card, it did not disappear. It's strange because It happens usually when I reduce a window or switch tab while using firefox.

My compositor is set to Xrender but disabling it did not solve the issue.

Edit: I noticed it happens just while using Firefox and that's also a common bug. Still I haven't found a solution.

Comment: did you try to disable webrender in FF : https://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-enable-or-disable-new-webrender-feature-in-mozilla-firefox/